# 'ascii' codec error can't decode byte 0xf3...when I'm using tia datamanager (bloomberg) in spyder enviroment

Tags: python, ascii, decode, spyder, bloomberg

When I try to import as follows (is bloomberg complement that allows retrieving data from bloomberg to python):

```
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm
```

I got this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)

This code works properly in my daily work, however I can't run this line at home.

Comment: Are you perhaps running it at work with Python 3 and at home with Python 2?

Comment: Alternatively, try declaring the encoding on the source file (the one being imported). Perhaps `latin1`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I'm working with python 2.7 in both cases. I will try your second suggestion...

Comment: I already tried the second suggestion and it didn't work, so I'm still stuck

Comment: What happens if you run the source file directly?

Comment: Do you have any idea what the offending characters are, why they're there, etc.? Does the file contain code not in English?

Comment: Do you think that this could be because of regional configuration ?

Comment: Yes, locale settings might have an influence. Really I don't know what I'm talking about and I'm poking around.